# Segment Image based on RGB Value on Quantized image

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

How would I segment the background from an image that has already been quantized(n=5/6)?

Assuming, I have a clean background color that is only one color, I think filtering out everything by either the rgb value of the top left or top right pixel would work great.

Ideally, I would like to avoid using openCV

Sample:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Compare each pixel color to the pixel in the top-left corner.  A pixel where all three layers of R, G, and B match is background:

```
mask = np.all(image == image[0, 0, :], axis=2)
```

Comment: Thanks

```from PIL import Image    
     
im = Image.open(file_name)    
img_array = np.asarray(im)    
mask = np.all(imag == imag[0, 0, :], axis=2)     
Image.fromarray(imag[~mask])    
   
imag.shape > (1983, 781, 3)   
imag[~mask].shape > (977221, 3)  
```
I lose the shape when I index back into the mask.

Comment: I guess what confuses me is this will end up as a polygon instead of a rectangle so how should I go about doing this?

Comment: @VinceKumar I don't know what exactly is `imag` in your code, but the snippet from Stefan returns a mast of shape `(986, 355)`. One can then change the values by `img[mask] = [255, 255, 255]` (will make the background white).